How can I create a "limited" webrtc-connection?
In my webrtc-applications (peers in javascript, Windows, Firefox, my signalling server in C++): 
peer1 starts the connection (sends offer) add tracks to the connection, peer2 gets offer and sends answer, adds own track.
All works good if user grants both peers all right to media (camera, mic) - getUserMedia resolved OK.
I'd like to create a "limited" connection: peer1 will not have rights for camera and mic, perr2 will have.
The problem is: peer1 can not call addTrack(), because it has not rights and tracks to send. So, negotiationneeded  is not fired for it.
The question is: how can peer1 can force negotiationneeded event to start a connection process - send your offer etc ?
RtcPeerConnection set up by the following function (peerConnection field is of the RTCPeerConnection type):

    function InitWebRTC(userRecord) {

        const config = {iceServers: []};

        try {
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
        }
        catch (err) {
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection = null;
        }

        if (userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection !== null) {
            
            if (settings.createDataChannel) {
                userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener("datachannel", rtc_OnRemoteDataChannel);
            }
            
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", rtc_OnIceCandidate);
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener("negotiationneeded", rtc_OnNegotiationNeeded);
            
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener("connectionstatechange", rtc_OnConnectionStateChange);
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange", rtc_OnIceConnectionStateChange);
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener("icegatheringstatechange", rtc_OnIceGatheringStateChange);
            
            let sigState = userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.signalingState;
            //userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.addEventListener('track', rtc_OnTrack);
            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.ontrack = rtc_OnTrack;

            userRecord.webRtc.peerConnection.onremovetrack = rtc_OnRemoveTrack;

        }

    } 


You don't need to add a track.  Show your JavaScript for how you're setting up the peer connection.

The RTCComnection doesn’t have any permission management. Just don’t add a track from your code.

@deceze, when peer1 does not have permissions, it simply does not add track, but in that case negotiationneed is not fired.

@LUN On StackOverflow and related sites, you can go back and edit your original question.  The formatting is much better there.

@Brad, I have added the code to original question. Also, I have noticed that in MSDN doc examples shown 2 cases of setting up event handler: pc.addEventListener and simply addEventListener for negotiationneeded. Which case should I use here ?

if you want to rely on the negotiationneeded event you can add a transceiver instead of a track using addTransceiver('video') and sets its direction to recvonly.

Philipp, if this peer will not send audio/video, but want to get it, should I add 2 transceivers: addTransceiver('video') and addTransceiver('audio') ?

yes. This is the same as addTrack but without a track essentially
